concatenate inner terraform blocks of a resource
I have an AWS Rule Group which is a part of AWS network firewall.
I need to be able to write rules in terraform when each rule will be in a separate file, and a way to merge (concatenate) all the rules under the rule group:
Here is an example of a rule group with 2 stateful_rule in it:
resource "aws_networkfirewall_rule_group" "test" {
  capacity    = 10
  description = test"
  name        = test"
  rules       = null
  tags        = {}
  tags_all    = {}
  type        = "STATEFUL"
  rule_group {
    rules_source {
      rules_string = null
      stateful_rule {
        action = "PASS"
        header {
          destination      = "1.1.1.2"
          destination_port = "25"
          direction        = "FORWARD"
          protocol         = "TCP"
          source           = "1.1.1.1"
          source_port      = "ANY"
        }
        rule_option {
          keyword  = "sid"
          settings = ["1"]
        }
      }
      stateful_rule {
        action = "PASS"
        header {
          destination      = "2.2.2.2"
          destination_port = "25"
          direction        = "FORWARD"
          protocol         = "TCP"
          source           = "2.2.2.3"
          source_port      = "ANY"
        }
        rule_option {
          keyword  = "sid"
          settings = ["2"]
        }
      }
    }
    stateful_rule_options {
      rule_order = "STRICT_ORDER"
    }
  }
}

I need to be able to write many tf files with this block
      stateful_rule {
        action = "PASS"
        header {
          destination      = "some dst ip"
          destination_port = "some dst port"
          direction        = "FORWARD"
          protocol         = "TCP"
          source           = "some source ip"
          source_port      = "ANY"
        }
        rule_option {
          keyword  = "foo"
          settings = ["bar"]
        }
      }

And a way to concatenate all stateful_rule blocks to one rule group (as the first example)
I have tried to work with the override mechanism but because the stateful_rule block is the same block name which repeats itself it just overrides the first block all the time

Curious why each rule would need to be in a different file. If you shed some light, maybe can advise a better solution that works with your processes, constraints and Terraform.

You could achieve that with a dynamic block, they have one example in the documentation:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/networkfirewall_rule_group#stateful-inspection-for-permitting-packets-from-a-source-ip-address
IN your code I see the difference is only the destination and the source, i'm going to assume that is the only thing, the code could be something like:
locals {
  stateful_rules = {
    1 = {
      destination = "1.1.1.2",
      source      = "1.1.1.1"
    },
    2 = {
      destination = "2.2.2.2",
      source      = "2.2.2.3"
    },
  }
}

resource "aws_networkfirewall_rule_group" "test" {
  capacity    = 10
  name        = "test"

  type = "STATEFUL"
  rule_group {
    rules_source {
      rules_string = null
      dynamic "stateful_rule" {
        for_each = local.stateful_rules
        content {
          action = "PASS"
          header {
            destination      = stateful_rule.value.destination
            destination_port = "25"
            direction        = "FORWARD"
            protocol         = "TCP"
            source           = stateful_rule.value.source
            source_port      = "ANY"
          }
          rule_option {
            keyword  = "sid"
            settings = ["1"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

The locals could be in one file the network resource in another
You could add more items to the stateful_rules or even more attributes to accomodate for more complex rules; play with that, it should do what you are asking.
